# Effectively using python map

Tags: python, dictionary

I have defined structure which looks like this. Basically a name value pair

```
from collections import namedtuple
CP = namedtuple('Cell', ['attr', 'value'])
```

This fits into a larger *ordered* structure which looks like this

```
_structure = [CP('id', None), CP('name', None)]
```

Then I get a series of results which correspond to three instances of `_structure`

```
results = [(1,'foo'),(2,"bar"),(3,"zaz")]
```

How do I `map` these into the following:

```
final = [[CP('id', 1), CP('name', "foo")],
         [CP('id', 2), CP('name', "bar")],
         [CP('id', 3), CP('name', "zaz")],]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a list comprehension:

```
final = [[CP('id', ident), CP('name', name)] for (ident,name) in results]
```

But you mentioned `map`, which you can also use:

```
final = map(lambda (ident,name): [CP('id',ident),CP('name',name)], results)
```

(Note that I didn't name the id variable `id` because that conflicts with an existing global function in Python.)

In Python, comprehensions/generators are generally preferred over `map`, because they're more general and arguably more legible.  Admittedly, the relative lack of generality in `map` is largely because Python's `lambda` construct for creating anonymous functions is rather limited compared to what's available in more functional languages, where `map` and friends reign supreme.

Comment: "comprehensions/generators are generally preferred over `map`" -- or anyway over `map` *with a lambda*. `map` with a named function that you have lying around tends to look a lot better so is a closer call. Not to say there aren't people who still prefer `[foo(x) for x in bar]` over `map(foo, bar)`, and especially over the Python 3 equivalent `list(map(foo, bar))`. I think it's further from unanimous, though.